# Python, cannot import name

Tags: python

I have 3 files lcdtest.py, lcd.py and alarmfunctionr.py. 
I am trying to control the attached lcd display on my raspberry pi with the lcdtest.py script.

```
!/usr/bin/env python
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import globals
import time
from alarmfunctionsr import SendToLCD
from lcd import noDisplay
from lcd import message

globals.init()

SendToLCD(12, "test lcd" ,1) #Test
time.sleep(5)

lcd.message("test with message")
time.sleep(5)

noDisplay
```

The import from alarmfunctionsr seem to work ok but i get an cannot import name error when i try the same for the lcd script.

lcd.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#
# based on code from lrvick and LiquidCrystal
# lrvic - https://github.com/lrvick/raspi-hd44780/blob/master/hd44780.py
# LiquidCrystal - https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal.cpp
#

from time import sleep


class CharLCD(object):

    # commands
    LCD_CLEARDISPLAY        = 0x01
    LCD_RETURNHOME          = 0x02
    LCD_ENTRYMODESET        = 0x04
    LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL      = 0x08
    LCD_CURSORSHIFT         = 0x10
    LCD_FUNCTIONSET         = 0x20
    LCD_SETCGRAMADDR        = 0x40
    LCD_SETDDRAMADDR        = 0x80

    # flags for display entry mode
    LCD_ENTRYRIGHT          = 0x00
    LCD_ENTRYLEFT           = 0x02
    LCD_ENTRYSHIFTINCREMENT = 0x01
    LCD_ENTRYSHIFTDECREMENT = 0x00

    # flags for display on/off control
    LCD_DISPLAYON           = 0x04
    LCD_DISPLAYOFF          = 0x00
    LCD_CURSORON            = 0x02
    LCD_CURSOROFF           = 0x00
    LCD_BLINKON             = 0x01
    LCD_BLINKOFF            = 0x00

    # flags for display/cursor shift
    LCD_DISPLAYMOVE         = 0x08
    LCD_CURSORMOVE          = 0x00

    # flags for display/cursor shift
    LCD_DISPLAYMOVE         = 0x08
    LCD_CURSORMOVE          = 0x00
    LCD_MOVERIGHT           = 0x04
    LCD_MOVELEFT            = 0x00

    # flags for function set
    LCD_8BITMODE            = 0x10
    LCD_4BITMODE            = 0x00
    LCD_2LINE               = 0x08
    LCD_1LINE               = 0x00
    LCD_5x10DOTS            = 0x04
    LCD_5x8DOTS             = 0x00

    def __init__(self, pin_rs=25, pin_e=24, pins_db=[23, 17, 27, 22], GPIO=None):
        # Emulate the old behavior of using RPi.GPIO if we haven't been given
        # an explicit GPIO interface to use
        if not GPIO:
            import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
            GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        self.GPIO = GPIO
        self.pin_rs = pin_rs
        self.pin_e = pin_e
        self.pins_db = pins_db

        self.GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        self.GPIO.setup(self.pin_e, GPIO.OUT)
        self.GPIO.setup(self.pin_rs, GPIO.OUT)

        for pin in self.pins_db:
            self.GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

        self.write4bits(0x33)  # initialization
        self.write4bits(0x32)  # initialization
        self.write4bits(0x28)  # 2 line 5x7 matrix
        self.write4bits(0x0C)  # turn cursor off 0x0E to enable cursor
        self.write4bits(0x06)  # shift cursor right

        self.displaycontrol = self.LCD_DISPLAYON | self.LCD_CURSOROFF | self.LCD_BLINKOFF

        self.displayfunction = self.LCD_4BITMODE | self.LCD_1LINE | self.LCD_5x8DOTS
        self.displayfunction |= self.LCD_2LINE

        # Initialize to default text direction (for romance languages)
        self.displaymode = self.LCD_ENTRYLEFT | self.LCD_ENTRYSHIFTDECREMENT
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_ENTRYMODESET | self.displaymode)  # set the entry mode

        self.clear()

    def begin(self, cols, lines):
        if (lines > 1):
            self.numlines = lines
            self.displayfunction |= self.LCD_2LINE

    def home(self):
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_RETURNHOME)  # set cursor position to zero
        self.delayMicroseconds(3000)  # this command takes a long time!

    def clear(self):
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_CLEARDISPLAY)  # command to clear display
        self.delayMicroseconds(3000)  # 3000 microsecond sleep, clearing the display takes a long time

    def setCursor(self, col, row):
        self.row_offsets = [0x00, 0x40, 0x14, 0x54]
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_SETDDRAMADDR | (col + self.row_offsets[row]))

    def noDisplay(self):
        """ Turn the display off (quickly) """
        self.displaycontrol &= ~self.LCD_DISPLAYON
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | self.displaycontrol)

    def display(self):
        """ Turn the display on (quickly) """
        self.displaycontrol |= self.LCD_DISPLAYON
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | self.displaycontrol)

    def noCursor(self):
        """ Turns the underline cursor off """
        self.displaycontrol &= ~self.LCD_CURSORON
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | self.displaycontrol)

    def cursor(self):
        """ Turns the underline cursor on """
        self.displaycontrol |= self.LCD_CURSORON
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | self.displaycontrol)

    def noBlink(self):
        """ Turn the blinking cursor off """
        self.displaycontrol &= ~self.LCD_BLINKON
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | self.displaycontrol)

    def blink(self):
        """ Turn the blinking cursor on """
        self.displaycontrol |= self.LCD_BLINKON
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_DISPLAYCONTROL | self.displaycontrol)

    def DisplayLeft(self):
        """ These commands scroll the display without changing the RAM """
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_CURSORSHIFT | self.LCD_DISPLAYMOVE | self.LCD_MOVELEFT)

    def scrollDisplayRight(self):
        """ These commands scroll the display without changing the RAM """
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_CURSORSHIFT | self.LCD_DISPLAYMOVE | self.LCD_MOVERIGHT)

    def leftToRight(self):
        """ This is for text that flows Left to Right """
        self.displaymode |= self.LCD_ENTRYLEFT
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_ENTRYMODESET | self.displaymode)

    def rightToLeft(self):
        """ This is for text that flows Right to Left """
        self.displaymode &= ~self.LCD_ENTRYLEFT
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_ENTRYMODESET | self.displaymode)

    def autoscroll(self):
        """ This will 'right justify' text from the cursor """
        self.displaymode |= self.LCD_ENTRYSHIFTINCREMENT
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_ENTRYMODESET | self.displaymode)

    def noAutoscroll(self):
        """ This will 'left justify' text from the cursor """
        self.displaymode &= ~self.LCD_ENTRYSHIFTINCREMENT
        self.write4bits(self.LCD_ENTRYMODESET | self.displaymode)

    def write4bits(self, bits, char_mode=False):
        """ Send command to LCD """
        self.delayMicroseconds(1000)  # 1000 microsecond sleep
        bits = bin(bits)[2:].zfill(8)
        self.GPIO.output(self.pin_rs, char_mode)
        for pin in self.pins_db:
            self.GPIO.output(pin, False)
        for i in range(4):
            if bits[i] == "1":
                self.GPIO.output(self.pins_db[::-1][i], True)
        self.pulseEnable()
        for pin in self.pins_db:
            self.GPIO.output(pin, False)
        for i in range(4, 8):
            if bits[i] == "1":
                self.GPIO.output(self.pins_db[::-1][i-4], True)
        self.pulseEnable()

    def delayMicroseconds(self, microseconds):
        seconds = microseconds / float(1000000)  # divide microseconds by 1 million for seconds
        sleep(seconds)

    def pulseEnable(self):
        self.GPIO.output(self.pin_e, False)
        self.delayMicroseconds(1)       # 1 microsecond pause - enable pulse must be > 450ns
        self.GPIO.output(self.pin_e, True)
        self.delayMicroseconds(1)       # 1 microsecond pause - enable pulse must be > 450ns
        self.GPIO.output(self.pin_e, False)
        self.delayMicroseconds(1)       # commands need > 37us to settle

    def message(self, text):
        """ Send string to LCD. Newline wraps to second line"""
        for char in text:
            if char == '\n':
                self.write4bits(0xC0)  # next line
            else:
                self.write4bits(ord(char), True)

def DisplayLCD(msg):
    lcd = CharLCD()
    lcd.clear()
    x=msg.find("**")
    if x>0:
        line1=msg[0:x]
        line2=msg[x+2:len(msg)]
    else:
        line1=msg
        line2=""
    lcd.message(line1+"\n"+line2)
```

alarmfunctionsr.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""


import globals
import urllib2
import smtplib
import serial
import time
import sys
import thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os, glob, time, operator
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from time import sleep

def find_all(a_str, sub):
        start = 0
        cnt=0
        while True:
                start = a_str.find(sub, start)
                if start == -1: 
                        return cnt
                start += len(sub)
                cnt=cnt+1

def isNumber(x):
        # Test whether the contents of a string is a number
        try:
                val = int(x)
        except ValueError:
                return False
        return True

def get_latest_photo(files):
    lt = operator.lt
    if not files:
        return None
    now = time.time()
    latest = files[0], now - os.path.getctime(files[0])
    for f in files[1:]:
        age = now - os.path.getctime(f)
        if lt(age, latest[1]):
            latest = f, age
    return latest[0]

def UpdateHostThread(function,opcode):
        try:
                thread.start_new_thread(UpdateHostThread, (function,opcode, ) )
        except:
                print "Error: unable to start thread"

def UpdateHost(function,opcode):
        # Sends data to the server 
        script_path = "https://www.privateeyepi.com/alarmhostr.php?u="+globals.user+"&p="+globals.password+"&function="+str(function)

        i=0
        for x in opcode:
                script_path=script_path+"&opcode"+str(i)+"="+str(opcode[i])
                i=i+1

        if globals.PrintToScreen: print "Host Update: "+script_path 
        try:
                rt=urllib2.urlopen(script_path)
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
                if globals.PrintToScreen: print "HTTP Error"
                return False
        time.sleep(.2)
        temp=rt.read()
        if globals.PrintToScreen: print temp
        l = find_all(temp,"/n");
        RecordSet = temp.split(',')
        c=[]
        y=0
        c.append([])
        for x in RecordSet:
                if x=="/n":
                        y=y+1
                        if y < l:
                                c.append([])
                else:
                        if isNumber(x):
                                c[y].append(int(x))
                        else:
                                c[y].append(x)
        rt=ProcessActions(c)
        if rt==False:
                return(False)
        else:
            return(c)

def ProcessActions(ActionList):
        FalseInd=True
        for x in ActionList:
            if x[0]=="/EMAIL":
                    SendEmailAlertFromRule(x[1], x[2],0)
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/SEMAIL":
                    SendEmailAlert(x[1])
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/CHIME":
                    StartChimeThread()
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/rn588":
                    exit()
            if x[0]=="/FALSE":
                    FalseInd=False
            if x[0]=="/SIREN":
                    StartSirenThread(x[2])
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/PHOTO":
                    SendEmailAlertFromRule(x[1], x[2],1)
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/RELAYON":
                    SwitchRelay(1)
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/RELAYOFF":
                    SwitchRelay(0)
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/WRELAYON":
                    SwitchRFRelay(1)
                    x.remove
            if x[0]=="/WRELAYOFF":
                    SwitchRFRelay(0)
                    x.remove
        return(FalseInd)

def StartSirenThread(Zone):
        try:
                thread.start_new_thread(Siren, (Zone, ) )
        except:
                print "Error: unable to start thread"

def SwitchRelay(onoff):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(globals.RelayPin, GPIO.OUT) 
        GPIO.output(globals.RelayPin,onoff)

def SwitchRFRelay(onoff):
        # declare to variables, holding the com port we wish to talk to and the speed
        port = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
        baud = 9600

        # open a serial connection using the variables above
        ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baud)

        # wait for a moment before doing anything else
        sleep(0.2)

        for i in range(0,3):
                if (onoff==True):       
                        ser.write('a{}RELAYAON-'.format(globals.WRelayPin))
                else:
                        ser.write('a{}RELAYAOFF'.format(globals.WRelayPin))
                time.sleep(2)
        ser.close

def SendToLCD(GPIOnumber, Location, status):
    import paho.mqtt.client as paho
    if status==0:
            ActionStr="_"
            topic="alarm_activity"
    else:
            if status==1:
                    ActionStr="_"
                    topic="alarm_activity"
            else:
                    topic="temperature"
                    if status==2:
                            ActionStr=str(GPIOnumber)+","+Location
                    else:
                            ActionStr="Undefined"

    #client = mosquitto.Mosquitto('privateeyepi')
    client = paho.Client()
    client.connect(globals.lcd_ip)
    if status <= 1:
            if globals.PrintToScreen:
                    print str(Location)+"**"+str(ActionStr)
            client.publish(topic, str(Location)+"**"+str(ActionStr))
    else:    
            if globals.PrintToScreen:
                    print str(ActionStr)
            client.publish(topic, ActionStr)
    client.disconnect()        

def Siren(Zone):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        if globals.UseSiren == True:
                GPIO.setup(globals.SirenGPIOPin, GPIO.OUT) #Siren pin setup
        else:
                return

        if globals.SirenDelay>0:
                globals.SirenStartTime = time.time()
                while time.time() < globals.SirenStartTime + globals.SirenDelay:
                        if globals.BeepDuringDelay:
                                GPIO.output(globals.SirenGPIOPin,True)
                                time.sleep(1)
                                GPIO.output(globals.SirenGPIOPin,False)
                                time.sleep(4)

        GPIO.output(globals.SirenGPIOPin,True)
        globals.SirenStartTime = time.time()
        if globals.PrintToScreen: print "Siren Activated"
        while time.time() < globals.SirenStartTime + globals.SirenTimeout:
                time.sleep(5)
                if CheckForSirenDeactivation(Zone) == True:
                        break
        GPIO.output(globals.SirenGPIOPin,False)
        if globals.PrintToScreen: print "Siren Deactivated"

def CheckForSirenDeactivation(Zone):
        # Routine to fetch the location and zone descriptions from the server 
        RecordSet = GetDataFromHost(16,[Zone])
        if globals.PrintToScreen: print RecordSet
        ZoneStatus=RecordSet[0][0]
        if ZoneStatus=="FALSE":
                return (True)    

def StartChimeThread():
        try:
                thread.start_new_thread(SoundChime, ())
        except:
                print "Error: unable to start thread"

def SoundChime():
        if globals.ChimeDuration>0:
                GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
                GPIO.setup(globals.ChimeGPIOPin, GPIO.OUT) #Siren pin setup
                GPIO.output(globals.ChimeGPIOPin,True)
                time.sleep(globals.ChimeDuration)
                GPIO.output(globals.ChimeGPIOPin,False)

def GetDataFromHost(function,opcode):
# Request data and receive reply (request/reply) from the server

        script_path = "https://www.privateeyepi.com/alarmhostr.php?u="+globals.user+"&p="+globals.password+"&function="+str(function)

        i=0
        for x in opcode:
                script_path=script_path+"&opcode"+str(i)+"="+str(opcode[i])
                i=i+1

        if globals.PrintToScreen: print script_path 
        try:
                rt = urllib2.urlopen(script_path)
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
                return False
        temp=rt.read()
        if globals.PrintToScreen: print temp

        l = find_all(temp,"/n");
        RecordSet = temp.split(',')
        c=[]
        y=0
        c.append([])
        for x in RecordSet:
                if x=="/n":
                        y=y+1
                        if y < l:
                                c.append([])
                else:
                        if isNumber(x):
                                c[y].append(int(x))
                        else:
                                c[y].append(x)
        rt=ProcessActions(c)   
        if rt==False:
                return(False)
        else:
            return(c) 
        return(c)

def BuildMessage(SensorNumber):
        # Routine to fetch the location and zone descriptions from the server  

        RecordSet = GetDataFromHost(6,[SensorNumber])
        if globals.PrintToScreen: print RecordSet
        if RecordSet==False:
                return  
        zonedesc=RecordSet[0][0]
        locationdesc = RecordSet[0][1]
        messagestr="This is an automated email from your house alarm system. Alarm activated for Zone: "+zonedesc+" ("+locationdesc+")"
        return messagestr

def BuildMessageFromRule(SensorNumber, smartruleid):

    RecordSet = GetDataFromHost(7,[smartruleid, SensorNumber])
    if RecordSet==False:
        return

    numrows = len(RecordSet)  

    messagestr="This is an automated email from PrivateEyePi. Rule triggered for Zone(s): "+RecordSet[0][3]+", Location: "+RecordSet[0][4]+" and for rule "
    for i in range(0,numrows,1):
        if RecordSet[i][0]==1:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Alarm Activated"
        if RecordSet[i][0]==2:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Alarm Deactivated"
        if RecordSet[i][0]==3:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Circuit Open"
        if RecordSet[i][0]==4:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Circuit Closed"
        if RecordSet[i][0]==5:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Open for " + str(RecordSet[i][1]) + " Minutes"
        if RecordSet[i][0]==6:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Closed for " + str(RecordSet[i][1]) + " Minutes"
        if RecordSet[i][0]==7:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Where sensor value (" + str(RecordSet[i][5]) + ") is between " + str(RecordSet[i][1]) + " " + str(RecordSet[i][2])            
        if RecordSet[i][0]==8:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Tamper"
        if RecordSet[i][0]==9:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Day Of Week is between " + str(RecordSet[i][1]) + " and " + str(RecordSet[i][2]) 
        if RecordSet[i][0]==10:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Hour Of Day is between " + str(RecordSet[i][1]) + " and " + str(RecordSet[i][2])
        if RecordSet[i][0]==11:
            messagestr=messagestr+"Where secondary sensor value (" + str(RecordSet[i][6]) + ") is between " + str(RecordSet[i][1]) + " " + str(RecordSet[i][2])
        if i<numrows-1:
            messagestr=messagestr + " AND "    
    return messagestr

def SendEmailAlertFromRule(ruleid, SensorNumber, photo):
        try:
                thread.start_new_thread(SendEmailAlertThread, (SensorNumber, ruleid, True, photo, ) )
        except:
                print "Error: unable to start thread"

def SendEmailAlert(SensorNumber):
        try:
                thread.start_new_thread(SendEmailAlertThread, (SensorNumber,0 , False, False) )
        except:
                print "Error: unable to start thread"

def SendEmailAlertThread(SensorNumber, smartruleid, ruleind, photo):

        # Get the email addresses that you configured on the server
        RecordSet = GetDataFromHost(5,[0])
        if RecordSet==False:
                return

        numrows = len(RecordSet)

        if globals.smtp_server=="":
                return

        if ruleind:
                msgtext = BuildMessageFromRule(SensorNumber, smartruleid)
        else:
                msgtext = BuildMessage(SensorNumber)

        for i in range(numrows):
                # Define email addresses to use
                addr_to   = RecordSet[i][0]
                addr_from = globals.smtp_user #Or change to another valid email recognized under your account by your ISP      
                # Construct email

                if (photo==1):
                        files = 0
                        files = glob.glob(globals.photopath)
                        latestphoto = get_latest_photo(files)
                        msg = MIMEMultipart()
                else:
                        msg = MIMEText(msgtext)

                msg['To'] = addr_to
                msg['From'] = addr_from
                msg['Subject'] = 'Alarm Notification' #Configure to whatever subject line you want

                #attach photo
                if (photo==1):
                        msg.preamble = 'Multipart message.\n'  
                        part = MIMEText(msgtext) 
                        msg.attach(part)
                        part = MIMEApplication(open(latestphoto,"rb").read())
                        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=latestphoto)
                        msg.attach(part)

                # Send the message via an SMTP server

                #Option 1 - No Encryption
                if globals.email_type==1:
                        s = smtplib.SMTP(globals.smtp_server)
                elif globals.email_type==2:
                #Option 2 - SSL
                        s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(globals.smtp_server, 465)
                elif globals.email_type==3:
                #Option 3 - TLS
                        s = smtplib.SMTP(globals.smtp_server,587)
                        s.ehlo()
                        s.starttls()
                        s.ehlo()
                else:
                        s = smtplib.SMTP(globals.smtp_server)


                s.login(globals.smtp_user,globals.smtp_pass)
                s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string()) 
                s.quit()
                if globals.PrintToScreen: print msg;

def SendCustomEmail(msgText, msgSubject):

        # Get the email addresses that you configured on the server
        RecordSet = GetDataFromHost(5,[0])
        if RecordSet==False:
                return

        numrows = len(RecordSet)

        if globals.smtp_server=="":
                return

        for i in range(numrows):
                # Define email addresses to use
                addr_to   = RecordSet[i][0]
                addr_from = globals.smtp_user #Or change to another valid email recognized under your account by your ISP      
                # Construct email
                msg = MIMEText(msgText)
                msg['To'] = addr_to
                msg['From'] = addr_from
                msg['Subject'] = msgSubject #Configure to whatever subject line you want

                # Send the message via an SMTP server
                #Option 1 - No Encryption
                if globals.email_type==1:
                        s = smtplib.SMTP(globals.smtp_server)
                elif globals.email_type==2:
                #Option 2 - SSL
                        s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(globals.smtp_server, 465)
                elif globals.email_type==3:
                #Option 3 - TLS
                        s = smtplib.SMTP(globals.smtp_server,587)
                        s.ehlo()
                        s.starttls()
                        s.ehlo()
                else:
                        s = smtplib.SMTP(globals.smtp_server)

                s.login(globals.smtp_user,globals.smtp_pass)
                s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
                s.quit()
                if globals.PrintToScreen: print msg;
```

Comment: can you copy the error message in your question please?

Comment: Your entire `alarmfunctionsr.py` file is one giant unclosed string, so either that isn't your actual code, or you're not really successfully importing from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lcd.py` module doesn't define any functions (or other top-level objects) named `noDisplay` or `message`, only a class named `CharLCD` and a function named `DisplayLCD`. So, when you try to import something that doesn't exist, of course you get an `ImportError`.

It's true that the `CharLCD` class has methods named `noDisplay` and `message`, but that doesn't mean you can just import them as top-level functions. (And, even if you could, you can't *call* them that way; you need a `CharLCD` object to call its methods.)

I suspect you need to read a basic tutorial on classes, like [the Classes chapter in the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Meanwhile, I think the code you want is:

```
from lcd import CharLCD

# ...

char_lcd = CharLCD()
char_lcd.message("test with message")
time.sleep(5)

char_lcd.noDisplay()
```

(Also note the `()` in the last line. You need those parentheses to call a function or method; without them, you're just referring to the function or method itself, as a value, which has no more effect than just writing `2` on a line by itself.)