# Python cannot import from another file name not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a custom function from another python file but keep getting an error `NameError: name 'testme' is not defined`. I confirmed that I am importing the file correctly according to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009668/python-cannot-import-name) and that [the function is top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843684/python-cannot-import-name). What else can I try to fix this?

My main python file is:

```
import sys
import dbconn
#from dbconn import testme #<----did not work


dev=True

if(dev):
    categId='528'
    pollIds=[529,530,531]
else:
    categId=str(sys.argv[1])
    pollIds=[529,530,531]


df=testme(categIds)#callServer(categId,pollIds)
df
if(not categId.isdigit):
    print('categ id fail. expected digit got: '+categId)
.....
```

and dbconn.py:

```
import pymysql #pip3 install PyMySQL
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
from scipy import stats

def testme(categIds):
    try:
        df=categIds
    except Exception as e:
        print("broke")
    return categIds
```

Not sure if it makes a difference but I am running the main python file from within a Jupyter notebook, and have a compiled version of dbconn.py in the same directory

In response to the suggestions I tried:

```
df=dbconn.testme(categIds)
```

got the error:

`module 'dbconn' has no attribute 'testme'`

Comment: Must be `dbconn.testme(...`.

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `from dbconn import testme`? And what happens if you change `df=testme(categIds)` to `df=dbconn.testme(categIds)`? Lastly, does it work if you run `import importlib; importlib.reload(dbconn)`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and updated my post with the results. Unfortunately it didnt work for me

Comment: The [official tutorial explains this pretty well](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). Your own modules are exactly like the ones you're using, like pandas and pymysql. So, when you `import dbconn`, the only thing you get in your namespace is the `dbconn` module itself, so you have to do `dbconn.testme` exactly like you have to do `pd.DataFrame`. If you `from dbconn import testme`, you get `testme` in your namespace instead, exactly like you get `pearsonr` from `scipy.stats.stats` and can then just use `pearsonr` directly.

Comment: If your edited version isn't working, you're doing something wrong that you aren't showing us. Because if I create your `dbconn.py` and `myscript.py` and run it, it works fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another `dbconn.py` somewhere else on your module path? Or that you just forgot to save the latest changes to `dbconn.py` so it doesn't actually have that `testme` method? Or that  your actual code has a typo and it defines `testem` instead?

Comment: There can be many reasons for that, but the first thing I usually do is in the importing file to `print(dbconn.__file__)` and check if the path is correct

Comment: @Rilcon42 You're not new to SO, you should know better than posting your solution into the question. If something you tried worked out for you, please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), posting an answer as an edit isn't appropriate.

Comment: Since your main code is in Jupyter -  this always catches me - if you modified the dbconn file to include testme after you started up your notebook then you need to restart your Jupyter kernel to pick up the change.

Answer (score -1):

You Have to follow these fox exact import

```
1)import <package>
2)import <module>
3)from <package> import <module or subpackage or object>
4)from <module> import <object>
```

in your case, you have tried

```
from dbconn import testme
```

you have to use only `packages` in `from` section and `module` in `import` section
like >>

```
from testme import dbconn
```